# Variable as an argument

Tags: php, function

I was wondering if i could pass a variable as an argument like in the following example:

```
function add_sales($checker){
$sales_payload = array(

    'organization_id' => $organization_id,
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
    'status' => 'Open',
    'subject' => " ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - ".implode(" ",$checker),
    'start_date' => date("Y-m-d"), // set start date on today
    'expected_closing_date' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+ 14 days")), // set expected closing date 2 weeks from now
    'chance_to_score' => '10%',
    'expected_revenue' => 0, //set the expected revenue
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],

    'progress' => array(
    'id'=>'salesprogress:200a53bf6d2bbbfe' //fill a valid salesprogress id to set proper sales progress 
    ),


    "custom_fields" => [["actief_in_duitsland"=>$value]],

);

// add the sales
$sales = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/sales/sales',json_encode($sales_payload));
}
```

This function has the variable $checker as argument.

I call this variable checker inside the function notice it in the next line:

```
'subject' => " ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - ".implode(" ",$checker),
```

And when i call the function i do it like;

```
$vertalingen_check = array_intersect($product_names , $vertalingen); 
$vertalingen_count = count($vertalingen_check);

if($vertalingen_count >= 1){
add_sales($vertalingen_check);
}else {}
```

Will this work? Passing a variable as an arguments like this? 
I hear you thinking, why dont you go ahead and test it to see for yourself. The problem is i can't test this for some complicated purposes. All i need to know is if something like this is possible

Comment: Sure it will work.

Comment: Why do you think that this may not work? I don't see anything special here.

Comment: It has to work, but I don't understand where do you pass the other variables that are used in that function?
`$organization_id`
`$strToRemove`
And where do you initialize the object you call at the end of this function:
`$SimplicateApi`

Comment: @ZoltánSüle I left that bit out, but that part is also inside the function normally, just left it out in this case

Comment: @Kevin.a then it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

For what it's worth, to make the answer more than just a "Yes", you're passing it by value by calling the function in that way.

Functionally, it's a good way to handle your use case.

Specifically, it's better than using a global variable.

```
function add_sales(){
    global $checker;
    $sales_payload = array(
```

Global variables make your code harder to maintain, because they introduce mechanisms whereby you can affect the value of a variable (and possibly overwrite variables that are in use in other places).

It's also better than passing it by reference.

```
function add_sales(&$checker){
    $sales_payload = array(
```